# GROOVYScript & Soapui : Store columns data retrieved by a single query

Tags: jquery, groovy, soapui, multiple-columns

I'm tryng to storage in my local variable with

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("FirstName", FirstName.toString());
```

and

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("SecondName", SecondName.toString());
```

data retrieved by a simple query like

```
select firstName, secondName
from users where c_fis='TRRKLA36C47I298D'
```

with a script looping for each column

```
def query = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "query" )

def rowNum = 1
sql.eachRow(query) { row ->
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("row"+rowNum, row.inspect());
rowNum++
}
sql.close()
```

but i cannot achieve my gol because the script store the resultset only in the first row.

I would like to store the value retrieved from each columns in every "rows".

Example

```
select firstName, secondName
    from users where c_fis='TRRKLA36C47I298D'
```

sets

```
Row1 = "John"
Row2 = "Smith"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by looping through the columns, like this:

```
def DBlist = sql.firstRow(query)
def columnNum = 1
DBlist.each {
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("colonna"+columnNum, 
    it.getValue().toString())
    columnNum++
}
```

Note that this script is only for one row, and you need to create as many column as you need if you are going to pass them among test cases.

Comment: Thanks for providing me this great solution!